# cant import vuex store to request file

Tags: vue.js, request, axios, store, vuex

i am trying to call a mutation when a request is sent and response has came. 
this is my request file:

```
 import axios from 'axios'
import router from '@/router'
import _ from 'lodash'

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.BASE_URL,
    timeout: 31000,
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
    },
});

const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
if(!_.isNil(token)) {
    instance.defaults.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
}


instance.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    return response
}, function (error) {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
        router.push('/introduction')
    }
});

export default instance
```

and this is my main store

```
const vuexLocal = new VuexPersistence({
    storage: window.localStorage
});

Vue.use(Vuex);
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://api.balatar.inpin.co/';
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    plugins: [vuexLocal.plugin],
    modules: {
            user,jobPost, company, application, cvFolder, event
        },
        state: {
            loader:''
        },
        getters: {

        },
        mutations: {
            LOADER:function (state, payload) {
                state.loader=payload;
                console.log('MUTATION')
            }
        },

        actions: {



        },
    });
```

when i try to import store like below

```
impotr {store} from '@/store/store'
```

and then access the LOADER mutation like this:

```
store.commit('LOADER')
```

it returns error that cannot read property commit of undefined. how should i do this?

Comment: try import (spelt correctly) store (no curly braces) from ...

Answer (score 0):

You should write an action, then send your request by your action and as soon as response arrives you will be able to `commit` a `mutation`

for example in the following action:

```
{
  /**
   * Login action.
   *
   * @param commit
   * @param payload
   */
  login: async function ({ commit }, payload) {
    commit('LOGGING_IN')

    try {
      const result = await fetchApi({
        url: 'http://api.example.com/login',
        method: 'POST',
        body: payload
      })
      commit('LOGIN_SUCCESS', result)
    } catch (error) {
      commit('LOGIN_FAILURE', error)
    }
  }
}
```

as you can see above, as soon as you call login, it calls `LOGGING_IN` mutation and sends a request to some address, then it waits for a response.
if it gets success response the `LOGIN_SUCCESS` mutation with a payload of result commits otherwise it commits `LOGIN_FAILURE` with a payload of cached error.

> note: you should provide your own `fetchApi` method which is a promise.